# Can a French citizen fly from France to the USA with a green card, but no passport?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, lost-documents, us-residents, french-citizens

I live in the US where I have a green card. I am in France (of which I am a citizen) and I lost my passport. Can I just use my green card to fly back to the US?

Comment: Do you have a French national ID card?

Comment: I edited the title to match the question body, since the answer may vary by destination country (especially if the destination country is also in the Schengen area.) Note also that if you're transiting a third country on the way to the U.S., you might also need the appropriate documents to enter that country if there is no international transit zone at the airport where the connection takes place.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You cannot use just a green card to fly from France to the US because you cannot clear the passport control for departing passengers with the green card.  For that, you'll need either a French passport (which you do not have) or a French national ID card.

Even if you have both the green card and the national ID, the airline might require you to have a passport, but TIMATIC, the database they normally use to verify immigration documents, suggests that the two documents are sufficient, so you might be in luck.

If you do not have an identity card, you [cannot get one urgently](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F16872), but you can make an [urgent application for a passport](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1373).  Acceptable reasons for such an application are limited, however.

As you have lost your passport, you may want to review [the relevant page at service-public.fr](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F21246).

Comment: Is there a document that can be obtained rapidly that can allow me to clear the departing passport control?

Comment: @azani you can try an urgent passport application, but you must have an acceptable reason; see the link above.

Comment: @azani Do you have a *carte d'identité*?

Comment: In my experience, the passport services in the small town  _mairies_ usually are most helpful in expediting passport delivery for emergency and work-related reasons. Last year, I realised a week before summer vacations that my son's passport had expired and managed to get a new one two days prior to departure, as the local officer called the _préfecture_ to ask for priority processing.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it was most helpful to me. I ended up bugging the consular staff to issue me an emergency passport instead of a laisser passer (which they already had) and so I did not end up in the above situation after all. The answer was helpful mostly because it told me I really really needed to avoid the above.

Answer (score 13):

You will need either a valid passport or valid *carte d'identité* (CNI) to exit France.

To enter the US, the Green card is enough, as stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=fr&AR=00&DE=us&AR=US&PASSTYPES=PASS&selDest=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20destination%28s%29%20above&TR=00&selTrans=Ukraine&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by airlines:

> Passport Exemptions:
>   - Passengers with a Permanent Resident/Resident Alien Card
>     (Form I-551).

If you have a CNI, and end up using that and the Green card, you should print the linked Timatic extract and underline the quoted section with a pen, as it is **not** widely known among check-in staff that green cards constitute a passport exemption for the US.

If they decide to double-check for themselves, remind them to put US in the "Alien residency" field, or the green card won't be listed.

Comment: Even if the traveler had a passport, the US residency would have to be noted because otherwise the system would require a visa or ESTA, no?

Comment: I travelled from the UK to the US with only my Green Card last year. I carried a print out from Timatic and a print out of the relevant section of US law. It was a pain and I had to wait around as the airline confirmed with their immigration officer and I got a pointless scolding from them, but I was able to travel.

Comment: @Dancrumb Could you please share the relevant section of US law that you showed to them?

Comment: @phoog Yes, but check-in agents often think a passport **and** green card is needed. Not correct

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Could be this https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1191/~/traveling-outside-of-the-u.s.---documents-needed-for-lawful-permanent-residents

Comment: Here's a link: https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-11261/0-0-0-15844/0-0-0-15873.html#0-0-0-9187

Title 8, Section 211.2(a)(2) and Section 211.1(a)(2)

Comment: Yeah - that CBP link references the point of law... wouldn't hurt to have them all printed out.

Comment: @Dancrumb since 212.2(a)(2) says "you need a passport except...," and then that relies on 211.1(a)(2), I would worry that trying to wade through the cross references with airline employees would be doomed to failure if they can't make sense of TIMATIC or the CBP page that Coke linked to in his comment.  Also, showing 211.1(a)(2) invites airline employees to start worrying about how long their passenger has been absent from the US.

Comment: @phoog Agreed, I would just stick to Timatic - in fact I've been told by Swissport, Dnata, AAS and Pegasus Ground Handling agents that even government website printouts mean **piss** to them. Once when Timatic's Italian sources screwed up royally, this cost me an extra day in Istanbul.

Comment: It is illegal for US citizens to exit US without a passport. There might be similar law in France.

Comment: @Evgeny A French citizen can exit France on a passport or national ID card

Comment: @Evgeny there is no penalty for unlawful departure from the US without a valid US passport in violation of 8 USC 1185(b), and there is no enforcement.  I don't see an analogous French law.

Comment: @Coke but can a French citizen exit France without either of those documents (for example, with a passport of another country)?

Answer (score 5):

Besides the legal requirements, you would always have to check with the airline. I know first hand of a case  where a passenger was denied at check-in with a combination of documents that immigration officer had confirmed to me were acceptable.

Because of the fines they receive when passegers are rejected, airlines tend to be overzealous about this.

Comment: The airline won't tell you anything on advance, so this advice is useless. In reality you have to check Timatic to verify what the airline's agent will see when you're boarding.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that front desk employees at a check in station in a small airport are able to read the exceptional cases in several paragraphs of a Timatic record. I can assure you, by personal many-times experience, that's not the case.

Comment: @MartinArgerami They are able to, but you might indeed need to "guide" them (for example by saying "put France in nationality and US in Alien residency. Then check below "Passport exemptions")

Comment: @JonathanReez Also it's usually not even the Airline that checks you, but a local handling Agent. So if anything you might want to contact *them*